# Geopandas geometry to lat/long

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, geopandas

```
df = gpd.read_file('/content/buildings.geojson')
```

df has a 'geometry' column with values like POINT (-12635143.897 7083229.283)

Reference image:

[image]

I have to change all the rows containing Point values to Latitude and Longitude (WGS84 coordinate system (i.e. EPSG=4326))

What's the best code for this?

Comment: can you provide a link to the geometry?  It would then be straight forward to provide you with an answer.  I would expect all you need is `df.to_crs("epsg:4326")`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what CRS the data currently is, thus if you need to re-project the points. But to get latitude and longitude, try this:

```
df["lat"]=df['geometry'].y
df["lon]=df['geometry'].x
```